# What are the rules on profile images?

Tags: discussion

What rules are there for acceptable or unacceptable profile images for the C SE community?

Answer (score 3):

Like with most offensive things, it can be hard to define strict rules, but [you know it when you see it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it). [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243388/256282) has some general principles. If you see someone has a profile image that you think is offensive, write a custom flag on one of their posts to alert the mods to them. If they don't have any posts, then alert the mods in chat I guess.